# Putting math symbol labels in ListPlot

Tags: plotting, labeling

I have a list of of points, and I want to label them $v_1$, $v_2$ etc. How do I go about that? Everywhere I look it seems I can only label using strings.

So let's say

```
data={{1,1},{2,2},{3,3}}
```

how do i lable each of these $v_1$,$v_2$,$v_3$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible way

```
data = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}
lbl = MapIndexed[Subscript[v, First[#2]] &, data ]
ListLinePlot[data -> lbl, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {0, 4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I had to add `PlotRange -> {0, 4}` due to clippling of last label:

```
 ListLinePlot[data -> lbl, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But I think there might be a better way to handle this label clipping at the end without having to explicitly give `PlotRange`. Will see if I can find one.

If you want to get a little more fancy, you can do

```
<< MaTeX`
data = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}
lbl = MapIndexed[MaTeX["v_" <> ToString@First[#2], Magnification -> 1.5] &, data]
ListLinePlot[data -> lbl, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 4}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That works, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `Callout` functionality:

```
data = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}
ListLinePlot[
 Table[
  Callout[data[[i]], Subscript[v, i], Above]
  , {i, Length@data}
  ]
 , Mesh -> All
 , MeshStyle -> Red
 , PlotRange -> {{0.5, 3.5}, {0.0, 3.2}}
 ]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

The good thing about `Callout` is the automatic placement of labels in a busy plot. Consider the following example.

```
data = Sort@RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {10, 2}];
pos = ConstantArray[Automatic, Length@data];
lbls = Subscript[v, #] & /@ Range[1, Length@data];
p1 = ListLinePlot[
  MapThread[Callout, {data, lbls, pos}]
  , GridLines -> Automatic
  , Mesh -> All
  , MeshStyle -> Red
  , AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio
  , PlotRange ->
   CoordinateBounds[data] + {{-0.6, 0.6}, {-0.6, 0.6}}
  ]
```

[image]